# Calling a JavaScript functions whose name is saved in a string

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to run a function whose name is saved in a string?

For example: I have three functions:

```
function nr1(p0, p1){
    /* [...] */
}
function nr2(p0, p1){
    /* [...] */
}
function nr3(p0, p1){
    /* [...] */
}
```

and I have a string whose content is a function name, for example:

```
var a_string = "nr2(27, 42)";
```

Is it possible to execute the function whose name is stored in the string?

Comment: if you know the parent object (e.g. `window`) then you can do e.g. `window['foo']()`

Comment: have you tried using `eval` ? try `eval(a_string);` note [eval is bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).. you should change your implementation

Comment: Possible? Maybe. A reasonable solution to anything? Almost never.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) it. Observe the following example...

```
function something() {
    console.log('did');
} 

var str = 'something()'

eval(str) // did
```

As comments suggest, not the best idea to take and run with - though it works... To expand on that just a bit more, I found this blog post which shares some good pointers on the somewhat controversial usage of this technique: [eval() isn’t evil, just misunderstood](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/)

---

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hho29bL/) - simple demo

Comment: @EisregenGruss36 you are most welcome! I also included a link to a blog post I felt was pretty interesting which should answer anything you'd like to know about `eval`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it and it works. I'm aware that it is probably not the best way to do it but I don't know how else I could do it. I am using it in Electron to send a String from the renderer process to the main process, in order to be able to execute main-process-functions from the renderer process.

Answer (score 1):

You can do eval, although it is frowned upon because of it's vulnerabilities. Something you could do is find it in the window object and then execute:

```
window["functionName"](args);
```

Calling with eval:

```
function test() { 
    console.log('test');
}

var fnstring = "test()";
eval(fnstring);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.
`eval(a_string)` but

[eval is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

- Improper use of eval opens up your code for injection attacks
- Debugging can be more challenging (no line numbers, etc.)
- eval'd code executes more slowly (no opportunity to compile/cache eval'd code)

you better change your implementation instead of saving a `string function call`

```js
function nr1(p0, p1){
    console.log('nr1 p0: ', p0);
    console.log('nr1 p1: ', p1);
}

function nr2(p0, p1){
    console.log('nr2 p0: ', p0);
    console.log('nr2 p1: ', p1);
}

function nr3(p0, p1){
    console.log('nr3 p0: ', p0);
    console.log('nr3 p1: ', p1);
}

var a_string = "nr2(27, 42)";

eval(a_string);
```